# HTML CSS JS Wave draw and animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I am working on an Ionic cross-platform mobile app and I have the basic design and layout completed. However, I want to implement some eye-catching design elements i.e. a "wave effect" on some pages.

***The 1st part*** would be to draw the waves on the screen.
The design I have mocked up in Photoshop is as below.

[image]

By the "wave effect," I mean the wavy lines that are the gradually increasing transparent lines between the pure white bottom section and the top yellow section.

In this case, there are 4 waves overlapping, each with 25% opacity giving the final 100% white opacity at the bottom.

If at all possible I would like them to intersect at the round pink + button as well. But this would be a "nice to have" feature.

***Secondly***, how would I animate the waves to move on e.g. a button click?
The idea is that when a user clicks the pink + button, the waves would move up to reveal more of the UI below.
Similar to [THIS](https://dribbble.com/shots/2208818-Yahoo-News-Digest-Redesign) effect.

I have no idea what this would even be called to Google it.
I have searched for waves or sine waves, but nothing similar to this.

Comment: How about 'wave animation'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create wave like images and using css set them to translate and scale at various rates. Something like four images scaling and translating at different rates should be able to give the illusion.

```css
@keyframes move_wave {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0) translateZ(0) scaleY(1)
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateX(-25%) translateZ(0) scaleY(0.55)
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(-50%) translateZ(0) scaleY(1)
    }
}
.waveWrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
.waveWrapperInner {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    bottom: -1px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #86377b 20%, #27273c 80%);
}
.bgTop {
    z-index: 15;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.bgMiddle {
    z-index: 10;
    opacity: 0.75;
}
.bgBottom {
    z-index: 5;
}
.wave {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 200%;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: repeat no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 bottom;
    transform-origin: center bottom;
}
.waveTop {
    background-size: 50% 100px;
}
.waveAnimation .waveTop {
  animation: move-wave 3s;
   -webkit-animation: move-wave 3s;
   -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
   animation-delay: 1s;
}
.waveMiddle {
    background-size: 50% 120px;
}
.waveAnimation .waveMiddle {
    animation: move_wave 10s linear infinite;
}
.waveBottom {
    background-size: 50% 100px;
}
.waveAnimation .waveBottom {
    animation: move_wave 15s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="waveWrapper waveAnimation">
    <div class="waveWrapperInner bgTop">
        <div class="wave waveTop" style="background-image: url('http://front-end-noobs.com/jecko/img/wave-top.png')"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="waveWrapperInner bgMiddle">
        <div class="wave waveMiddle" style="background-image: url('http://front-end-noobs.com/jecko/img/wave-mid.png')"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="waveWrapperInner bgBottom">
        <div class="wave waveBottom" style="background-image: url('http://front-end-noobs.com/jecko/img/wave-bot.png')"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Try this links for references:

1. [Css Wave Animation](https://codepen.io/joshbader/pen/BzVmVw)
2. [PNG Wave Animation](https://codepen.io/plavookac/pen/QMwObb)
3. [waves-animation github](https://github.com/CesarNog/waves-animation)

Also searching for html wave animation gives quite interesting results.

Answer (score 0):

In a project of ours to accomplish something similar to what you described, we designed 4 gifs with different opacity and set them to the background on top of each other. They looked very nice but did slow the mobile devices a bit!

Comment: It would be an option but if it slows the app down I would like to explore other possibilities if at all possible. But if there are no alternatives it will certainly be at the top of the list.